# Nextauth Twitter - Function not found with Netlify dev

Tags: twitter, netlify, next-auth

I couldn't find any reference to this and finally managed to solve problem.

When using Nextauth with Twitter (and probably other providers) you get a 'Function not found...' error if you are using Netlify dev.

Error in the console is: "Warning: Missing form submission function handler"

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something to do with the Netlify dev proxy. If you use :8888 which is the front-facing server then no go, however, if you use the :3000 port server that sits behind it, it's fine. I assume the netlify dev server is picking up on something first.

If anyone has more information please do let me know. For the time being, using the alternative server is fine for testing as I'm not also trying to use Netlify functions.

Comment: Did you find more explanation regarding this issue? I'm confused on that one.

Comment: me too. same issues. posted a bit on it at https://answers.netlify.com/t/3000-8888-port-conflict-with-netlify-dev-and-nextauth-on-localhost/94398

Comment: Answer was not to use netlify dev when testing this.